# Create a route from a list of points Gmap

Tags: winforms, routes, gmap.net

I'm currently working on an windows forms application that is fetching a list of PointLatLng from a server and displays them on a map.

Here is what I managed to do so far (Drawing lines between all points):

```
private void DrawRoute()
{
       List<PointLatLng> inter = new List<PointLatLng>();
       //--- 
       GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapOverlay markers = new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapOverlay("markers");
       //--- Creating the "Start" marker below
       GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapMarker marker_start = new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogle(
            new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(points[0].Lat, points[0].Lng),
            GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogleType.arrow);
        marker_start.ToolTipText = "Start";

        //--- Center the map on the Start marker
        _Map.Position = new PointLatLng(points[0].Lat,points[0].Lng);
        _Map.MinZoom = 5;
        _Map.MaxZoom = 100;
        _Map.Zoom = 14;
        //---
        GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapOverlay polyOverlay = new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapOverlay("polygons");
        for (int i=0; i<points.Count -2; i++)
        {
                anterior = false;
                //--- Adding a GmapPolygon with only 2 points (Drawing a line on the map)
                inter.Add(points[i]);
                inter.Add(points[i + 1]);
                GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapPolygon polygon = new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapPolygon(inter, "mypolygon");
                polygon.Fill = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Red));
                polygon.Stroke = new Pen(Color.Red, 5);
                polyOverlay.Polygons.Add(polygon);
                _Map.Overlays.Add(polyOverlay);
                inter.Remove(inter[1]);
                inter.Remove(inter[0]);
        }
        //-- Creating the "Finish" marker
        GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapMarker marker_finish = new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogle(
            new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(p_anterior.Lat , p_anterior.Lng),
            GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogleType.arrow);
        marker_finish.ToolTipText = "Finish";
        //--- Adding the "Start" and the "Finish" marker on map
        markers.Markers.Add(marker_start);
        markers.Markers.Add(marker_finish);            
}
```

Is there any possibility for me to create a route from that list of points using gmap library?

Comment: Is this a WPF project? Asking because of fully qualified marker referencing Winforms, please specify.

Comment: it is a windows forms application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a route is as simple as passing a `List<PointLatLng>` to `GMapRoute` and add that to an overlay:

```
val route = new GMapRoute(points, "sample route");

route.Stroke = new Pen(GetRandomColor());
route.Stroke.Width = 4;
route.Stroke.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.DashDot;
route.Stroke.StartCap = LineCap.NoAnchor;
route.Stroke.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.ArrowAnchor;
route.Stroke.LineJoin = LineJoin.Round;

routes.Routes.Add(route);
```

When in doubt [check the sample at github](https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps/blob/master/Demo.WindowsForms/Forms/MainForm.cs#L1011).